# Issue with line breaks with Phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer

Everybody says to use \n as break line for plain text; how ever i have tried everything and it wont work, someone could give me a hand here please. With quotes, without quotes. Please tell me the proper way to do it. Here is my code:

```
include("class.phpmailer.php");   
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSendmail();
$mail->setFrom('info@test.org', 'test');
$mail->addAddress('test@hotmail.com');
$mail->Subject = $title;   
$mail->Body = ''.$descrip.' "\n" Vid Upl by '.$name.'';
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo "Msg sent!";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mail->Body = ''.$descrip.' "\n" Vid Upl by '.$name.'';
```

should be

```
$mail->Body = $descrip . "\nVid Upl by " . $name;
```

or for short

```
$mail->Body = "$descrip\nVid Upl by $name";
```